# How to quit click after some specific event

Tags: github, networking, click, router

I am trying to generate UDP packets for benchmarking purposes.
my click configuration file: `fastudp.click`

```
/*
 * Author: Anuraag
 */

// FastUDPSource(RATE, LIMIT, LENGTH, SRCETH, SRCIP, SPORT, DSTETH, DSTIP, DPORT [, CHECKSUM, INTERVAL, ACTIVE])

FastUDPSource(1000, 2000, 64, 78:32:1b:71:81:b8, 192.168.0.250, 5432, FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF , 192.168.0.1, 5433)->ToDevice(enp2s0);
```

The command that I run to use click:

```
sudo click fastudp.click -h fudp.rate -h fudp.count
```

After 2 seconds, when I press `CTRL+C`:

```
^Cfudp.rate:
1000

fudp.count:
2000
```

What do I want?

> I want a method/workaround so that the program automatically quits after sending the `2000` packets and displays the handler details `fudp.rate` and `fudp.count`

Any suggestion/comments are **appreciated**, thanks in advance

Comment: Click here means the **Click Modular Router**, [GitHub Link](https://github.com/kohler/click)

Answer (score 0):

You typically use the [Script](https://github.com/kohler/click/wiki/Script) element or [DriverManager](https://github.com/kohler/click/wiki/DriverManager) element for these types of things. As an example, run the config and stop after 2 seconds:

```
fudp::FastUDPSource(1000, 2000, 64, 78:32:1b:71:81:b8, 192.168.0.250, 5432, FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF , 192.168.0.1, 5433)->ToDevice(enp2s0);

Script ( 
    wait 2,
    printn "fudp.rate: ",
    print fudp.rate,
    printn "fudp.count: ",
    print fudp.count,
    stop
)
```

Credits:

- [Beyers Cronje](https://github.com/bcronje)
- [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/kohler/click/issues/443)